# Sequelize not adding record in through/junction table whenever I try to add a Server to a User model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `Server` and `User` models and I've set a `many-to-many` relationship between them like this:

```
User.belongsToMany(Server, { through: 'Server_Users' });
Server.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'Server_Users' });
```

Then I get a user by his `id`, create a server and attempt to add the server to the user like this:

```
let user = await User.findByPk(userId)

    let socketServer = await Server.create({
        name: name,
        thumbnail: thumbnail,
        userId: userId
    });

    await user.addServer(socketServer)
```

This creates and inserts the server in the database, however, it doesn't create the relationship between the user and the server in the junction `server_users` table. I don't get any errors either so I've no clue what is going on.

The logging shows an INSERT for the server and then some sort of update:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = '1';
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `servers` (`id`,`userId`,`name`,`thumbnail`,`endpoint`,`rooms`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
Executing (default): UPDATE `servers` SET `userId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` IN (25)
```

Comment: turn on loggin in Sequelize and look at SQL queries.

Comment: @Anatoly I've added the log to my question. I see the SELECT for the user, and the INSERT for the server. Not sure what the UPDATE does in this case.

Comment: comment `await user.addServer(socketServer)` line and look at SQL log again. Will UPDATE disappear?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, it disappears.

Comment: given that it's a many-to-many relationship, it looks a bit suspicious that there is a `userId` column in the `servers` table..

Comment: It means you have TWO links from Server to User and addServer just sets userId in a server record. Maybe you should revise your DB structure?

Comment: The userId is to determine who is the owner/creator of the server, whereas the many-to-many relationship is to determine who has joined the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
await user.addServer(Server, socketServer);
```

From documentation [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html#instance-method-add](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7EBelongsToMany.html#instance-method-add)

By the way, if you do it like this you will use 2 DB calls. You can reduce it to one by using .createServer method.

Please read it here: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html#instance-method-create](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7EBelongsToMany.html#instance-method-create)